# How to develop a HTML front-end plugins for elasticsearch

Tags: plugins, elasticsearch

This is not rocket science, but if you want to do a UI-only plugin for elastic search, it is not readily revealed by the top Google (or StackOverflow) search hits, so I thought I'd ask-and-answer here:

How do you develop a "head-only" (i.e. lacking any server-side Java code) HTML-frontend for ElasticSearch?  The documentation and guides concentrate on Maven and jar files, but all I want is to create a simple query UI and have that UI be hosted by elasticsearch itself.

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch's plugin folder structure looks like this:

```
/[es-home]/plugins/my-plugin/_site
```

Elasticsearch's HTTP server will happily serve static content from within the `_site` path.  Furthermore, it will serve `index.html` as the default document for the main plugin url (e.g. `http://my-es-server:9200/_plugin/my-plugin`).  Given this, it's simple to create a static HTML/CSS/JS site that uses relative urls to query the elasticsearch instance and display the results in a browser.  [`elasticsearch-head`](http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/) is an example of this kind of plugin.